# Replacing XML content

Tags: xml, xpath

If I have this:

```xml
<div id="wrapwrap">
    <header>
      <div id="foo"/>
    </header>
</div>
```

I want to replace `<div id="foo"/>` with `<span id="bar"/>`

Is this a valid XPath syntax?

```xml
<xpath expr="//div[@id='wrapwrap']/header" position="replace">
   <span id="bar"/>
</xpath>
```

Note: I am using a framework and getting an error but I can not determine if it is because of the XPath or because of the framework syntax. That is why I am trying to double check my XPath to center troubleshooting on the framework.

Comment: Missing the name of the framework

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of

```
expr="//div[@id='wrapwrap']/header"
```

use

```
expr="//div[@id='foo']"
```